# Functionality level configurable logger enable in Log4j2

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I want to implement a logger at a functionality level in my application. so when and where log needed for debugging I can turn on and start logged activities. For example, i want to enable logging for registration functionality only.

I am not sure that this is possible or not but my requirement is like that. If possible please give a solution or any insight on that is appreciatable.

Comment: I really don't think that is some auto logger for method calls (unless some advanced framework exists). Otherwise I can suggest to create bean for logger (with configuration) and inject it into class. Logger will detect where it was called. At least it works with `slf4j`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the slf4j/log4j API, this is a feature you get pretty much "for free".  If you follow the standard practice of creating a logger for each of your classes, via a line like:

```
static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserRegistration.class);
```

and use that logger for all logging in that class.  You also choose the appropriate log level for each of your logging calls (WARN, INFO, DEBUG, etc.).  Then you can turn the log level up/down in your logging configuration file for just one class with a line like this:

```
<logger name="com.mycompany.util.registration.UserRegistration"><level value="DEBUG"/></logger>
```

You can also turn the logging level up/down for the whole module that this class comes from with a line like:

```
<logger name="com.mycompany.util.registration"><level value="DEBUG"/></logger>
```

You use config lines like these to turn on certain log calls by raising them above the default log level you've set.  You set the default log level with something like this:

```
<root><level value="WARN" /></root>
```

So with just these lines, you would only get WARN level logging for most of your code, but for that one module or class file, you'd also get INFO and DEBUG level logging.

You can do more complicated things, like send logging for certain parts of your code to a special log file.  Maybe that's what you're talking about when you say you only want to log "registration functionality".  You could set up your logging config so that only classes involved in "registration" are sent to a special file.

The main point of this is that you don't need to think about this too much in advance.  You just attach the name of each class to all the logging calls made in that class, and choose the appropriate log level (WARN, INFO, DEBUG) for each of your logging calls, and you can decide later via your logging config file what you want to see or not see, and where you want logging information to go.

You can use API calls to configure logging more dynamically when your program first starts, or even while it is running.  The main point, again, is that you don't think ahead about which parts of your code you want to see detailed logging for.  You just put logging calls everywhere, and then decide which ones you actually see the output from later on.